# Software written in grapa can write to stderr when redirected to a file, but not to a terminal

Tags: linux, shell, stderr

I have been having some issues redirecting stderr to stdout with linux shell.

The program I'm trying to test with is written as follows (referred to below as `some-binary`):

```
#!/bin/sh
grapa -ccmd '$file().set("/dev/fd/2","Error\n")'
```

The following does work:

```
$ ./some-binary < ./my_input 2>test.txt
$ cat test.txt
Error
$
```

(The output is saved to file)

But this does not for me:

```
$ ./some-binary < ./my_input 2>&1
$
```

(There is not output)

I don't understand why this is. Could someone please clarify?

---

This can be reproduced with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal-20220801
RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget freeglut3 libxft2 libxext6 libxinerama1 libxcursor-dev -y
RUN wget https://github.com/grapa-dev/grapa/raw/master/bin/grapa-ubuntu64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf grapa-ubuntu64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
```

```
docker run -it $(docker build -q .) /bin/bash
root@db9abeca8b5f:/# grapa -ccmd '$file().set("/dev/fd/2","Error\n")' >/dev/null 2>test.txt
root@db9abeca8b5f:/# cat test.txt 
Error
root@db9abeca8b5f:/# grapa -ccmd '$file().set("/dev/fd/2","Error\n")' >/dev/null 2>&1      
root@db9abeca8b5f:/#
```

Comment: what is the result of `sh -c "./some-binary" < ./my_input` without `2>&1`

Comment: @EchoMike444 It seems to be blank I tried echo \"\`sh -c "./some-binary" < ./my_input\`\" and is printed `""`

Comment: What is `some-binary`?  Many programs modify their output depending on whether or not they are writing to a tty.  It seems unusual to modify error messages depending on if stderr is a tty, but that seems to be what is happening.  Or, perhaps the message ends with `\r` instead of `\n`.  Pipe it to xxd: `./some-binary 2>&1 | xxd`

Comment: @WilliamPursell The out from piping to `xxd` seems to be empty. So, maybe it is handling tty differently

Comment: I think it is using `/dev/fd/2` for stderr in case that has any effect

Comment: "/dev/fd/2" is just reopening wherever your stderr already goes. _Usually_ that's a noop. (It sometimes can fail if that's something like a UNIX domain socket that needs to be wired up with `connect()` instead of `open()`; that's the case for the systemd journal, for example). But we can't conclusively answer this without a [mre] that includes something that behaves enough like your actual binary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Anyhow -- `strace`, `ltrace`, &c. to figure out what your binary are doing is an excellent place to start. If the binary is choosing a different path, then that means the shell isn't doing anything wrong in the first place and the question is entirely mistagged.

Comment: ...on the other hand, if you just want a cheap and easy workaround, `sh -c 'unbuffer ./some-binary'` (after installing `expect`) and there you are. `unbuffer`, as a side effect, makes _every_ possible stdin/stdout/stderr look as if it were a TTY.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I just tried `sh -c 'unbuffer ./some-binary 2>&1' 2>&1` and it still doesn't seem to be displaying the output, but I will take a look at `strace` and `ltrace` to see if I can find the issue

Comment: Heh. Given what that other guy found, if you were watching with strace you would have seen `seek()` calls fail.

Comment: Yeah, line 1144-1145 from strace has:
`lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)`
`lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirection is fine. Grapa just doesn't support canonical file IO.

Here's the documentation for Grapa's `$file().set`:

> Updates the column in a row. By default the $VALUE column is updated. But an alternate column can be specified.

As suggested, it's meant for structured file IO. Here's [the source code](https://github.com/grapa-dev/grapa/blob/2b3d6ec42d02dfdcefe856352e7f59e7f05921e6/source/grapa/GrapaDatabase.cpp#L1171-L1175):

```c
        u64 size = pValue.mLength;
        err = mFile.SetSize(size);
        err = mFile.Write(0, 0, 0, size, pValue.mBytes);
        mFile.Purge(size, 1);
        err = mFile.Close();
```

And the [Write function](https://github.com/grapa-dev/grapa/blob/2b3d6ec42d02dfdcefe856352e7f59e7f05921e6/source/grapa/GrapaFileIO.cpp#L201-L212):

```c
    err = GetSize(fileSize);
    if (err)
        return((GrapaError)-1);
    [...]
    endPos = lseek(mFp, (blockPos*blockSize + offset), SEEK_SET);
    if (endPos != (blockPos*blockSize + offset))
        return((GrapaError)-1);
```

As you can see, it strongly assumes the file is seekable, and bails if it isn't. This means you can't use this function to write to terminals, pipes, or anything that's not a basic file.

The class says "This class/libraries will be enhanced over time to support navigating data types beyond the file system and the grapa database". You can consider filing a feature request.